# binding listbox and refresh data in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I've bound one listbox between property variable and ItemSource of Listbox in XAML with MVVM pattern.

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="lbTemp" ItemsSource="{Binding SrcPermissionList}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public List<CheckBox> SrcPermissionList= new List<CheckBox>();
CheckBox ckbox = new CheckBox();
SrcPermissionList.Add(ckbox);
```

Then it caused a STA thread accessing issue because I tried to add the checkbox in dynamic way. As for the data it's obtaining by Service+Server. So I used Dispatch code to fix that.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate ...
```

After all, it kinda seems like doesn't work but when I debugged, it actually has data inside. Before try to manipulate the listbox such as clicking it or scrolling it down, it renders nothing as shown below.

[Image of listbox which is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np1UJ.png)

I donno how to refresh the bound listbox without touching the listbox.
Data show at least I click only 1 time, or only 1 tick of scrolling.
I think it may have problem among the threads. and UI thread doesn't know when the itemsource came.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't touch it from a different thread (or Invoke into the UI thread if you must). And use binding instead of codebehind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)

ObservableCollection is a collection that allows code outside the collection be aware of when changes to the collection (add, move, remove) occur.

```
 private ObservableCollection<Type> collection;
```